# How to read a large image with tiff format in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to read a large image with tiff format in Matlab?

I am trying to read an image with the size of 1.970.654 k in matab and later on I would like to crop the image into tiles. When I use the imread code it gives me an error of :

'Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.'

I would really appreciate it if sb could kindly help me with it.

Comment: Look at the PixelRegion option to IMREAD

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough memory? If you only have 2 GB of memory I doubt there is even enough memory allocated to Matlab to do that.

Also, a workaround might just be to use another editor to split the image into separate sets of TIFFs and then perform your analysis on each set.